# R database connection encoding mistakes with accents

Tags: r, database, character-encoding

I am connecting to a SQL Server database using this code:

```
DBI::dbConnect(odbc(), 
               Driver = "...", 
               Server = "...", 
               Database = "...", 
               UID = "...", 
               PWD = "...", 
               Port = ...)
```

And later I amb extracting a table using the function `dbGetQuery`.

The problem is that I have columns with accents (spanish language) in the SQL Server, I can see them correctly there, but when I get the table in R I cannot see them correctly, I see the symbol � in the letters with accents.

How could I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work to add the argument `encoding = <the encoding of your database>` to `DBI::dbConnect()`.

Do you know the encoding your database is using? If not, I would try `latin1` first, as that is rather common for western european languages (se e.g. [here](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-import.html#readr-strings)).

So try changing your code to:

```r
DBI::dbConnect(
  odbc::odbc(), 
  Driver = "...", 
  Server = "...", 
  Database = "...", 
  UID = "...", 
  PWD = "...", 
  Port = "...",
  encoding = "latin1"
)
```

Comment: Oh thank you! It worked. But I still have one doubt, I used this code SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Collation') and I got "Latin1_General_CI_AI", so I put encoding = "Latin1_General_CI_AI" in the dbConnect function and good, I didn't get an error. But later when using the dbGetQuery I got this error: Error in iconv(x[current], from = enc, to = to, ...) : 
  unsupported conversion from '' to 'Latin1_General_CI_AI' in codepage 1252

Isn't it weird? But thanks, the "latin1" worked well.

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe Latin1_General_CI_AI is too specific, and the dbGetQuery  doesn't know how to translate between this and the encoding your system is using. I'm glad "latin1" works.